# How to configure a single akka-http GET to not retry

Tags: akka-http

The [`akka.http.client.host-connection-pool.max-retries`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/configuration.html) entry can be used to disable automatic retries of idempotent queries, on an application level.

However, I haven't found how to apply such a configuration to only a single kind of request.

The answer cannot be to make the GET request idempotent. It is. But the application logic requires a retry to continue with different parameters (updated cursor); any attempt to retry with the old ones is harmful at best.

Using Akka-http 2.4.7.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to not use a pool for these requests that cannot be retried, instead just using `outgoingConnection`?  That way there would be no retry logic.

Comment: Oh, I am using `outgoingConnection`. So there's no problem - just my misunderstanding.

Comment: Are you referring to `akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-retries` (without `client` part) property?